# How do I get HDFS bytes read and write for Spark applications?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to collect different metrics for the spark application, if some one have any idea about how do i get HDFS bytes read and write please tell me?

Comment: have you had a look at this? http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#metrics

Comment: yes, I have seen. But these apis are not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for the same information and I can't find the information anywhere: neither Spark documentation or the Spark users mailing list (even if some poeple are [asking the question](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-metrics-explanation-tt23149.html)) is giving me the information.

But, I found [some](http://www.hammerlab.org/2015/02/27/monitoring-spark-with-graphite-and-grafana/) [clues](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/get-CPU-Metrics-from-spark-tt615.html#a706) over the internet that suggest that it is provided by Spark in the metrics.

I'm working on some application logs (the ones that are provided by the history server) and it seems that the `Input Metrics` and `Output Metrics` that are presents in `Task Metrics` in each `SparkListenerTaskEnd` events is giving the amount of data that is read and written for each tasks.

```
{
  "Event": "SparkListenerTaskEnd",
  ...
  "Task Metrics": {
      ...
      "Input Metrics": {
        "Bytes Read": 268566528,
        "Records Read": 2796202
      },
      "Output Metrics": {
        "Bytes Written": 0,
        "Records Written": 0
      },
      ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Note that I'm not a 100% sure on that but the log I got seems to be consistent with this assumption :)

Also, If you are reading from local filesystem I think this will be mixed in the same metric.

Comment: do you know how it get HDFS read count? I didn't find any metric counter represent HDFS read/write operation count.