# SPARK : How to access AzureFileSystemInstrumentation when using azure blob storage with spark cluster?

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, metrics

I am working on a *spark* project where the storage sink is Azure Blob Storage. I write data in parquet format. I need some metrics around storage, eg. `numberOfFilesCreated`, `writtenBytes` etc. On searching for it online I came across a particular metrics that the `hadoop-azure` package has called the `AzureFileSystemInstrumentation`. I am not sure about how to access the same from spark and can't find any resources for the same. How would one access this instrumentation for the given spark job?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, I think there are three solution can be used in your current scenario, as below.

1. Directly use [Hadoop API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/index.html) for HDFS to get HDFS Metrics Data in Spark, because `hadoop-azure` just implements the HDFS APIs for using Azure Blob Storage, so please see the Hadoop offical document for [Metrics](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Metrics.htm) to know what particular metrics you want to use, such as `CreateFileOps` or `FilesCreated` as the figure below to get `numberOfFilesCreated`. Meanwhile, there is a similar SO thread [How do I get HDFS bytes read and write for Spark applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715858/how-do-i-get-hdfs-bytes-read-and-write-for-spark-applications) which you can refer to.

   [image]
2. Directly use Azure Storage SDK for Java or other languages you used to write a program to do the statistics for files stored in Azure Blob Storage as blobs ordered by creation timestamp or others, please refer to the offical document [`Quickstart: Azure Blob storage client library v8 for Java`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java-legacy) to know how to use its SDK.
3. Use Azure Function with Blob Trigger to monitor the events of files created in Azure Blob Storage, then you can write the code for statistics on every blob created event, please refer to the offical document [`Create a function triggered by Azure Blob storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function) to know how to use Blob Trigger. Even, you can send these metrics what you want to Azure Table Storage or Azure SQL Database or other services for statistics later in the Azure Blob Trigger Function.